# Looking for an analysis book which uses linear maps notation for multivariable differentiation

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

I'm taking an analysis course and I find it quite hard to follow what the professor is saying. So far we've been following elementary real analysis by bruckner^2 and Thompson but for the topic on multivariable differentiation, my professor opted not to follow the textbook. He mentioned that the mentioned book's approach is rather painful and introduced the following  approach in class via a lemma by Hadamard. Everything else we discuss is built on this lemma which places emphasis on linear maps, space of linear maps, etc.

The Lemma is as follows:

> Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be open and $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ then $f$ is differentiable at $a \Leftrightarrow \exists \,\,\,\gamma_a:U\rightarrow L(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R^n})$ continuous at $a$ such that $$f(x)=f(a)+\gamma_a(x-a)$$

Here, $L$ is the space of linear maps.

I am wondering if anyone here knows of a book which follows such an approach in the study of multivariable differentiation. Honestly, I understand what the professor is saying but the notation he has presented so far is what I find confusing. I'd prefer to be able to read a book as I don't catch everything during the lecture.

Thanks for the help/suggestions!